# Error while building Qt6 from source using x86_64-w64-mingw32

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I am trying to build Qt6 for Windows using *x86_64-w64-mingw32* from Linux (Ubuntu 23.10).

My problem is when I am trying to use CMake for the [QtBase repo](https://github.com/qt/qtbase), I encounter this error which I can't fix:

```
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:\
IMPORTED_IMPLIB not set for imported target "zstd::libzstd_shared"\
configuration "Release".
```

[The whole `stderr` and `stdout` of CMake](https://termbin.com/1wl0):

```
% cmake -DQT_ALLOW_SYMLINK_IN_PATHS=1 --toolchain ~/mingw-w64-x86_64.cmake -DQT_HOST_PATH=../build/lib/cmake/Qt6HostInfo -GNinja ..

CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:49 (message):
  The path "/home/alexsm/LinuxFiles/Workshop/programs/qtbase/build-mingw"
  contains symlinks.  This is not recommended, and it may lead to unexpected
  issues.  If you do not have a good reason for enabling
  'QT_ALLOW_SYMLINK_IN_PATHS', disable it, and follow one of the following
  solutions:

      - Map directories using a transparent mechanism such as mount --bind
      - Pass the real path of the build directory to CMake, e.g. using
        cd $(realpath <path>) before invoking cmake <source_dir>.
               
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:63 (qt_internal_check_if_path_has_symlinks)


-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.0.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.0.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Setting build type to 'Release' as none was specified.
            -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG=-g
            -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-O3 -DNDEBUG
            -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG
            -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG=-g
            -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-O3 -DNDEBUG
            -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG
            -DCMAKE_OBJCOPY=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-objcopy
            -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/alexsm/LinuxFiles/Workshop/projects/auxillary/mingw-w64-x86_64.cmake
            -DCMAKE_C_STANDARD=11
            -DCMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED=ON
            -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17
            -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED=ON
            -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:STRING=/home/alexsm/LinuxFiles/Workshop/programs/qtbase/cmake/platforms

-- Configuration summary shown below. It has also been written to /home/alexsm/LinuxFiles/Workshop/programs/qtbase/build-mingw/config.summary
-- Configure with --log-level=STATUS or higher to increase CMake's message verbosity. The log level does not persist across reconfigurations.
 
-- Configure summary:

Building for: win32-g++ (x86_64, CPU features: )
Compiler: gcc 12.0.0
Build options:
  Mode ................................... release
  Optimize release build for size ........ no
  Fully optimize release builds (-O3) .... no
  Building shared libraries .............. yes
  Unity Build ............................ no
  Relocatable ............................ yes
  Using precompiled headers .............. yes
  Using Link Time Optimization (LTCG) .... no
  Using Intel CET ........................ no
  Target compiler supports:
    x86 Intrinsics ....................... Basic VAES AVX512VBMI2
  Sanitizers:
    Addresses ............................ no
    Threads .............................. no
    Memory ............................... no
    Fuzzer (instrumentation only) ........ no
    Undefined ............................ no
  Build parts ............................ libs
  Install examples sources ............... no
  App store compliance ................... no
Qt modules and options:
  Qt Concurrent .......................... yes
  Qt D-Bus ............................... yes
  Qt D-Bus directly linked to libdbus .... no
  Qt Gui ................................. yes
  Qt Network ............................. yes
  Qt PrintSupport ........................ yes
  Qt Sql ................................. yes
  Qt Testlib ............................. yes
  Qt Widgets ............................. yes
  Qt Xml ................................. yes
Support enabled for:
  Using pkg-config ....................... no
  Using vcpkg ............................ no
  udev ................................... no
  OpenSSL ................................ no
    Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ no
  OpenSSL 3.0 ............................ no
  Using system zlib ...................... no
  Zstandard support ...................... yes
  Thread support ......................... yes
Common build options:
  Linker can resolve circular dependencies  yes
Qt Core:
  backtrace .............................. no
  DoubleConversion ....................... yes
    Using system DoubleConversion ........ no
  GLib ................................... no
  ICU .................................... no
  Using system libb2 ..................... no
  Built-in copy of the MIME database ..... yes
  Application permissions ................ yes
  Tracing backend ........................ <none>
  OpenSSL based cryptographic hash ....... no
  Logging backends:
    journald ............................. no
    syslog ............................... no
    slog2 ................................ no
  PCRE2 .................................. yes
    Using system PCRE2 ................... no
Qt Sql:
  SQL item models ........................ yes
Qt Network:
  getifaddrs() ........................... no
  IPv6 ifname ............................ no
  libproxy ............................... no
  Schannel ............................... yes
  DTLS ................................... no
  OCSP-stapling .......................... no
  SCTP ................................... no
  Use system proxies ..................... yes
  GSSAPI ................................. no
  Brotli Decompression Support ........... no
  qIsEffectiveTLD() ...................... yes
    Built-in publicsuffix database ....... yes
    System publicsuffix database ......... no
Core tools:
  Android deployment tool ................ no
  macOS deployment tool .................. no
  Windows deployment tool ................ no
  qmake .................................. yes
Qt Gui:
  Accessibility .......................... yes
  FreeType ............................... yes
    Using system FreeType ................ no
  HarfBuzz ............................... yes
    Using system HarfBuzz ................ no
  Fontconfig ............................. no
  Image formats:
    GIF .................................. yes
    ICO .................................. yes
    JPEG ................................. yes
      Using system libjpeg ............... no
    PNG .................................. yes
      Using system libpng ................ no
  Text formats:
    HtmlParser ........................... yes
    CssParser ............................ yes
    OdfWriter ............................ yes
    MarkdownReader ....................... yes
      Using system libmd4c ............... no
    MarkdownWriter ....................... yes
  EGL .................................... no
  OpenVG ................................. no
  OpenGL:
    Desktop OpenGL ....................... no
    Dynamic OpenGL ....................... yes
    OpenGL ES 2.0 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.0 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.1 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.2 ........................ no
  Vulkan ................................. no
  Session Management ..................... yes
Features used by QPA backends:
  evdev .................................. no
  libinput ............................... no
  HiRes wheel support in libinput ........ no
  INTEGRITY HID .......................... no
  mtdev .................................. no
  tslib .................................. no
  xkbcommon .............................. no
  X11 specific:
    XLib ................................. no
    XCB Xlib ............................. no
    EGL on X11 ........................... no
    xkbcommon-x11 ........................ no
    xcb-sm ............................... no
QPA backends:
  DirectFB ............................... no
  EGLFS .................................. no
  EGLFS details:
    EGLFS OpenWFD ........................ no
    EGLFS i.Mx6 .......................... no
    EGLFS i.Mx6 Wayland .................. no
    EGLFS RCAR ........................... no
    EGLFS EGLDevice ...................... no
    EGLFS GBM ............................ no
    EGLFS VSP2 ........................... no
    EGLFS Mali ........................... no
    EGLFS Raspberry Pi ................... no
    EGLFS X11 ............................ no
  LinuxFB ................................ no
  VNC .................................... no
  VK_KHR_display ......................... no
  QNX:
    lgmon ................................ no
    IMF .................................. no
  XCB:
    Using system-provided xcb-xinput ..... no
    GL integrations:
      GLX Plugin ......................... no
        XCB GLX .......................... no
      EGL-X11 Plugin ..................... no
  Windows:
    Direct 2D ............................ yes
    Direct 2D 1.1 ........................ yes
    DirectWrite .......................... yes
    DirectWrite 3 ........................ yes
Qt Widgets:
  GTK+ ................................... no
  Styles ................................. Fusion Windows WindowsVista
Qt Testlib:
  Tester for item models ................. yes
  Batch tests ............................ no
Qt PrintSupport:
  CUPS ................................... no
Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. no
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... yes
  PostgreSQL ............................. no
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
  Mimer .................................. no
 

WARNING: QT_ALLOW_SYMLINK_IN_PATHS is enabled. This is not recommended, and it may lead to unexpected issues.
E.g., When building QtWebEngine, enabling this option may result in build issues in certain platforms.
See https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59769.
WARNING: Basic cpp/winrt support missing. Some features might not be available.

-- 

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'cmake --build . --parallel'

Once everything is built, you must run 'cmake --install .'
Qt will be installed into '/usr/local/Qt-6.7.0'

To configure and build other Qt modules, you can use the following convenience script:
        /usr/local/Qt-6.7.0/bin/qt-configure-module

If reconfiguration fails for some reason, try removing 'CMakeCache.txt' from the build directory
Alternatively, you can add the --fresh flag to your CMake flags.

-- Configuring done (22.7s)
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB not set for imported target "zstd::libzstd_shared"
  configuration "Release".


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB not set for imported target "zstd::libzstd_shared"
  configuration "Release".


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB not set for imported target "zstd::libzstd_shared"
  configuration "Release".


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB not set for imported target "zstd::libzstd_shared"
  configuration "Release".


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB not set for imported target "zstd::libzstd_shared"
  configuration "Release".


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB not set for imported target "zstd::libzstd_shared"
  configuration "Release".


-- Generating done (0.4s)
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

I tried to build [zstd](https://github.com/facebook/zstd) using *x86_64-w64-mingw32* and add a parameter for CMake like below:

```
cmake -DQT_ALLOW_SYMLINK_IN_PATHS=1 --toolchain ~/mingw-w64-x86_64.cmake 
-DQT_HOST_PATH=../build/lib/cmake/Qt6HostInfo 
-GNinja 
-DIMPORTED_IMPLIB=~/zstd/build-mingw/lib/libzstd.dll ..
```

But I get the same output. I do not know what to do with that (maybe I used the `IMPORTED_IMPLIB` arg incorrectly).

The [CMake toolchain file](https://gist.github.com/peterspackman/8cf73f7f12ba270aa8192d6911972fe8) I used:

```
# Sample toolchain file for building for Windows from an Ubuntu Linux system.
#
# Typical usage:
#    *) install cross compiler: `sudo apt-get install mingw-w64`
#    *) cd build
#    *) cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/mingw-w64-x86_64.cmake ..
# This is free and unencumbered software released into the public domain.

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX x86_64-w64-mingw32)

# cross compilers to use for C, C++ and Fortran
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-g++)
set(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gfortran)
set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-windres)

# target environment on the build host system
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX})

# modify default behavior of FIND_XXX() commands
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

Comment: Can I interest you in [quasi-msys2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2)? It lets you download prebuilt Qt, among other packages.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I interested for real. I tried that and it cmake'ed. That incredible, but I've encountered some errors.

Comment: Can you add the errors, and the commands you ran?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I've downloaded qt6-base package and tried to plug both exe files inside bin folder as the qt framework into my QtCreator but it wrote me "Qt version is not properly installed, please run make install". So I've decided to your env to build qt-base I got from git, And its' cmake really does that without errors. But ninja throws the error "ninja: error: '~/qtbase/build/lib/cmake/Qt6HostInfo/libexec/qvkgen', needed by 'src/gui/vulkan/qvulkanfunctions.h', missing and no known rule to make it".

Comment: This is the command I ran to cmake qtbase package:
cmake -DQT_ALLOW_SYMLINK_IN_PATHS=1 -DQT_HOST_PATH=../build/lib/cmake/Qt6HostInfo -GNinja ..
UPD: oh I see that QT_HOST_PATH is reudant. I ran cmake without it and used ninja. So i've got another error

Comment: Here's the output of ninja command: https://termbin.com/rfpw

Comment: I'll take a look how to integrate it into QtCreator tomorrow. Wouldn't try to build qt6-base from source, since it's likely going to produce the same thing you can download with `make install _qt6-base` in quasi-msys2.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, fine. Thank you! So please write to me tomorrow in case you find out how to use `_qt6-base` via _QtCreator_

Comment: I've added an answer. This required patching quasi-msys2 a bit, make sure you pull the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of building Qt on your own, you can download a prebuilt one for MinGW from [Quasi-MSYS2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2).

> I leave here the [reference](https://github.com/Alexcoratt/ColorCalc_GUI) to the project I am trying to build

Install Quasi-MSYS2 as explained in the readme. Use it to install Qt: `make install _qt6-base _qt6-tools`.

Run CMake: `cmake -B build`, `cmake --build build`.

I'm getting some compilation errors related to incorrect usage of `unsinged long` instead of `std::size_t`, but that's on you to fix.

Comment: Hello! I've tried to do that following your instructions but there is the problem. I am using some subprojects which are using Qt5 framework parts. I can remove it but if only I do that It stops building since cmake cannot find libraries I've included in files.

Maybe I did something wrong, but I was strictly following your guide.

I leave here the [reference](https://github.com/Alexcoratt/ColorCalc_GUI) to the project I am trying to build. If you have enough time, please, check that out.

Comment: @Alexcoratt Ah, you should've linked that from the very begining. I got sidetracked configuring QtCreator, because I thought you want it specifically, but you don't actually need it, just build from the command line. I got it to pass the CMake configuration, but there's way too many errors related to mixing `unsigned long` and `size_t`, which are different types on Windows (`long` is 32 bits there).

Comment: So I tried to build it as you said, but there still an errors while using cmake.

Here is the [link](https://termbin.com/5st4) to `stdout` and `stderr` after I ran command `cmake --debug-find-pkg=Qt6Widgets -DQT_DEBUG_FIND_PACKAGE=ON`

Excuse me please if I do something wrong but I do following your guides. I appreciate your support for real

Comment: @Alexcoratt Can you show the complete log, including quasi-msys2 initialization log? One thing I see so far is that you didn't install Clang (see quasi-msys2 readme), so it instead runs MSYS2's GCC using Wine, which is really really slow (and sometimes doesn't work correctly, maybe this is the issue here).

Comment: I've noticed that I forgot to install `Clang` and `LLD` packages in `quasi-msys2` and to create a symlink to the `/ucrt64`. Now I corrected that and `cmake` works correctly, but `make` throws an error. I pass [the link to the output](https://termbin.com/ivpv) of `env/shell.sh`, `cmake` and `make` commands.

P.S. Before all this actions I've performed command `bash -c "$(wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh)"`

Comment: @Alexcoratt *"I forgot to install Clang and LLD packages in quasi-msys2"* Nah, you don't need them, I'd uninstall them just in case. You need just the normal Clang, not the MSYS2 one. The last command in your comment should've installed it for you. If it didn't, can you re-run it and show the log?

Comment: Sure. Here is the [link](https://termbin.com/3sgk) for the output

Comment: @Alexcoratt I see errors related to MXE repos. Remove them from the repo list and try again.

Comment: @Alexcoratt Overall, it looks like `apt update` is broken for you for the same reason, so you'll need to fix it anyway.

Comment: Hello! I'm sorry I was not responding for a while. I fixed my apt and all is working and compiling now, so thank you very much! I really appreciate your support! But there are some new errors. Anyway these new problems are not related to `quasy-msys2`. I am just trying to link windows required qt shared libraries

Comment: Btw, even if I copy all DLLs from `quasy-msys2/root/ucrt64/bin/` to my application's directory It still breaks throwing error with message `This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem`. I wonder is that possible to run Qt-based application on a windows host which has no Qt installed?

Comment: @Alexcoratt Qt has something called [`winqtdeploy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-deployment.html). I haven't used it (nor Qt) much, but I assume it packages all the necessary DLLs somehow. Yes, your users shouldn't need to install Qt separately.

Comment: I tried to use quasi-msys2 to build the simple “Hello world” gtkmm-based application and that did it perfectly. So now I am thinking about to transfer my app from Qt to GTK